# If / Else order

Tags: javascript, react-native, bluetooth

I have a question. I Have this code:

```
firstScan(){
    this.manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
      if (error) {
        return
      }
      if(device.name == this.model_1(this.props.Model)) {
          this.manager.stopDeviceScan()
            console.log("Device 1 OK")
            this.secondScan();
      }
          else {
            console.log("Error Device 1")
          }
      })
  }
  secondScan(){
    this.manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
      if (error) {
        return
      }
      if(device.name == this.model_2(this.props.Model)) {
          this.manager.stopDeviceScan()
            console.log("Device 2 OK")
            this.check();
      }
          else {
            console.log("Error Device 2")
          }
      })
```

I have 2 bluetooth device, I want to check if they are present or not.
So I scan and check if they are.

I would know why in the console I receive messages in this order:

> Error Device 1
>
> Device 1 OK
>
> Error Device 2
>
> Device 2 OK

In your opinion how can I fix?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved with a flag.

```
firstScan(){
    var flag = false
    this.manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
      if (error) {
        return
      }
      if(device.name == this.model_1(this.props.Model)) {
          this.manager.stopDeviceScan()
            console.log("Device 1 OK")
            flag = true
            this.secondScan();
      }
          else if (flag == false) {
            console.log("Error Device 1")
          }
      })
  }
```